# Solving quadratic equations in modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a general way to solve quadratic equations modulo *n*? I know how to use Legendre and Jacobi symbols to tell me if there's a solution, but I don't know how to get a solution without resorting to guesswork. Some examples of my problems:

$x^2 = 8$ mod 2009
$x^2 + 3x + 1 = 0$ mod 13

Thanks

Comment: The first problem, with no cross terms, is [hard](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/03/07/computing-modular-square-roots-in-python/) in general.  The second one can be reduced to the first by completing the square.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on the value of the modulus $n$.

- in general, if $n$ is composite, then solving modulo $n = \prod p_i^{e_i}$ is equivalent to solve modulo each $p_i^{e_i}$. However, this requires knowing the factorization of $n$, which is hard in general (in a computational way): there are cryptosystems based on this.
- modulo a prime $p \neq 2$, you may simply complete the square and proceed in exactly the same way as in the reals.
- modulo the prime $p = 2$, it is impossible to complete the square. Instead, the relevant way to solve quadratic equations is through [Artin-Schreier theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory): basically, instead of $x^2 = a$, your “standard” quadratic equation is here $x^2-x = a$. (Well, this is useful for extensions of the field $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, but not so much for this field itself, since you can then simply enumerate the solutions...).
- modulo a power $p^e$, you start by computing an “approximate” solution, that is, a solution modulo $p$. You may then refine this solution to a solution modulo $p^e$ by using [Hensel's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma). Note that this works for both the equations $x^2 = a \pmod{p \neq 2}$ and $x^2 - x = a \pmod{2}$ as stated above.

This means that the only remaining problem is how to compute a square root modulo a prime $p$. For this, the relevant reference would be the Tonnelli-Shanks algorithm; see for instance Henri Cohen's [*A Course in computational algebraic number theory*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hXGr-9l1DXcC), 1.5.1.

Comment: For modulo a prime p not equals 2, what is the "same way as in the reals"?

Comment: In the same way as far as deciding the existence goes (except the sign is replaced by the Jacobi symbol). For computing the solution, it is different: you use the structure of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$. I edited my answer to add a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm expected to do these by hand!

Comment: @user221330 See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1248710/107671) for how to solve any quadratic congruence mod $p\neq 2$.