# How to find a solution to $x^2 \equiv 7 \pmod{787}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Find a solution to $x^2 \equiv 7 \pmod{787}$.

The answer should be between $1$ and $786$ but beyond that I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257648/solving-quadratic-equations-in-modular-arithmetic

Comment: since 787 is a bigger prime, this is hard. But at least you know $x \equiv 7^{788/2} = 7^{394} \mod 787$.

Comment: I looked over it but still don't really understandit

Comment: aras why is that useful?

Comment: Your prime $787$ is small enough that if you are not doing a test at the time you can make a spreadsheet or small program to quickly find the answer. If you know neither spreadsheets nor programming, you should learn!

Answer (score 2):

*"Find a solution to $x^2 \equiv 7 \pmod{787}$"*

[Here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%5Cmod%28x%5E2%2C+787%29%3D7) the solution. We have two solutions, given your constraints, $x=105$ and $x=682$.

$$105^2=11025=3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2 \equiv 7\mod 787$$
$$682^2=2^2 \cdot 11^2 \cdot 31^2 \equiv 7 \mod 787$$

These can be proved to be the only solutions by using proof by exhaustion. If you want a derivation use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1248710/219489) answer. In general, this is the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm). Please read up on that and then come back.

We have $p=787$ and $n=7$. We also have $7^{(787-1)/{2}} \equiv 1$. Now we see that,

$$787-1=786=393 \cdot 2=393 \cdot 2^1=Q \cdot 2^S$$

We have $Q=393$ and $S=1$ so we are done. The solution is given by,

$$7^{(787+1)/4} \mod 787=7^{197} \mod 787=105$$

Which can be solved using the Carmichael function and friends. After that,

The other solution is therefore $787-105$. So the solutions are $x=105$ and $x=682$.

Comment: Well, yes thank you for doing that but why is that the case? Why are those the solutions?

Comment: @user274933 I can show you that they work. That's why they're the solutions. Do you want a derivation?

Comment: I did not understand why someone downvoted this!

Comment: I've been trying to understand how to derive it from the last sentence of your answer but it's still tricky. Yes, I would appreciate a derivation.

Comment: @user274933 I can do that, but it won't be an immediate solution.

Comment: Ok that's fine.  I'm also trying to understand why $x = a^{(p+1)/4}$ is a solution to the congruence $x^{2} \equiv a (modp)$. So I think this is related. Anything you could say about that would be appreciated

Comment: Given that p is a prime satisfying $p \equiv 3 (mod4)$ and a is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ I mean.

Comment: @user274933 There you go. Please read closely...

Answer (score 1):

Note that I am working in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ where $p$ is a prime (i.e. the elements are equivalence classes, so that I don't need to use (mod $p$)).

As easily follows from Fermat's little theorem $a^p= a$ for all $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. It follows that if $p +1$ is divisible by $4$, and $x^2 = a$, then $( a^{\frac{p+1}{4}})^2 = ((x^2)^{\frac{p+1}{4}})^2= x^{4 \frac{p+1}{4}}=x^{p+1}=x^2=a$. This tells us that if $a$ has square roots they can be computed as $\pm a^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$.

In your example we compute $x=[7]^{197}=[105]$ and the other one as $-x = [682]$.